# How to dynamically update an OSGi bundle?

Tags: dynamic, osgi, updates

I want to dynamically update a bundle in OSGi framework.
Here, i want to preserve the component state. I know that the update command in OSGi ignores maintaining state of component.

I want to find a OSGi update framework like DSUF : http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2127719

Regards.

Comment: you do mean by "maintaining state" ? If you want to keep the content of a map that is instanciated by the bundle, it is not possible

Comment: yes, the content (or value) of a variable in a current bundle that i want to keep in the new one. This is maybe a global variable.

Answer (score 3):

Updating a bundle means a new class loader for the updated bundle. So this means first stopping the bundle, updating it to the new version and then restarting the bundle using the new version. So components will also be stopped and restarted using the implementation classes in the new version of the bundle.

A component can save some state during deactivation that it could restore during re-activation, but this would need to be part of the component's implementation.

Comment: Could you please tell me more detail how to maintain state ? If possible, please let me know a framework more famous to maintain state during update an OSGi bundle ?

Comment: Only your component knows what is its "state". So only your component knows what to preserve as state during a bundle update.

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way i can see is to save and restore the context by yourself, through a persistent mechanism (jdbc, file writing, jms, ...).

Comment: Here, this is not simple to save and restore the context. Maybe there are the data in thread that is executing, for example, the communication requests. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_software_updating. I want to find a framework like Pymoult but for OSGi